# Periodic Internet connection loss with TP-LINK 4300 router

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

I have an issue with my TP-LINK TL-WDR4300 router. Since I bought it, I had some issues with connectivity, but after I disabled the hardware NAT option and re-flashed the firmware to the *same* latest version, everything went well for the long 2 months. I actually haven't had any problems with it until now.

What is wrong now? After I turn it on, it can work for some time, say for a few hours. Then I don't have the Internet for all devices in home (two notebooks, two phones, a tablet).

To check things, I login to the router admin panel (there's no problem with this, WiFi functionality is up and working). It shows that it is registered within the network (I see the router WAN IP WAN on the status page). I go to the diagnostic page and try to ping 8.8.8.8. It doesn't work (100% packets loss). I therefore assume that the router doesn't have a link to the Internet. At the same time the hardware light indicator on the router that is intended to show whether I have Internet connection up or not is blinking with different timings. This I suppose means that the router considers the connection as the working one. This is wrong, since I can't ping anything.

If I reboot the router with the hardware button, in most cases it gets alive and the Internet is working again, but in some cases the situation stays the same, even after several reboots in a row. In addition, if I connect the Ethernet cable from my ISP directly to a notebook, the Internet is always available.

I am using the vendor's native firmware. I tried to check the logs, but the interface is not user-friendly enough to do that. However, what I see is that there is no suspicious information there at the moment of the supposed connection drop. Actually, there was no data at all for at least two hours prior to the issue occurring.

What should I do to get this resolved? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you ever encounter problems when you connect a computer to the router via Ethernet when the router is connected to the upstream ISP ethernet cable? In other words, do you ONLY experience WiFi problems, or is it both WiFi *and* Ethernet when connecting to that router?

Comment: I actually didn't use the Ethernet connection, since I don't have a standalone PC in my home, so WiFi is just fine for me. And this doesn't seem to be WiFi problem at all, as I can connect to the router admin panel via WiFi. The router wasn't able to ping Google DNS server 8.8.8.8. The only thing that came to my mind is to check the connectivity between the devices in the home network via WiFi to see that this is related to Internet only.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the problem. In my case it was caused by a TP Link Powerline adapter, AV200 Wireless. When I've stopped to use this, problem was solved.

Comment: Explain how, you dropped your comment as answer and it could be a good and the right answer. you have chosen the easy way.